# Execute tzutil.exe from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, process, uac

I have some other process executing .exe file and works fine. Some need to be put on batch file.

Now I face problem with the tzutil.exe which it always failed over access denied permission.

Here is the command:

```
tzutil.exe /s "timezone name"
```

I have done many as follow:

1. WCF run on IIS 7.5 and app pool is set to local system.
2. I have tried to supply user credential to the process but failed.
3. Put into batch file before executing, still failed. If I run manually the batch file, it works fine.
4. I have also tried to set administrator in full control in the registry key \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\gpsvc and add SeTimeZonePrivilege in the RequiredPrivileges key. Restart the computer and try again. Keep failed.
5. I have add "Everyone" for "Change the timezone" in the Local Security Policy. Still failed. Also tried to add all available user and group in list. Try to add IIS App pool but it said "Failed to save to local policy database."
6. I also tried to use psexec.exe. I have to access not remotely but still inside WCF service => 'psexec.exe tzutil.exe /s "timezone name"'. Still failed. It works fine if run manually.

Any other suggestion and fix is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can troubleshoot issues like this using Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and hopefully you'll see what operation exactly fails with access denied.

Comment: You probably need to run it elevated ("Run as administrator").